# Visual Studio C++ MFC Stack Trace with mostly just external stack frames - finding the cause

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have a stack trace, in Visual Studio of an application using C++ MFC which has crashed.

I have the debugger open, with a stack trace, but I cannot tell what the cause is. All of the stack frames, are external besides the entry point that calls to display a modal dialog.

---

> How can I go about finding the cause of this, or debug this problem? (Why is the stack not of my code, but all external?)

---

This is the only call in the stack *frame* that is relevant to the code I have.

`INT_PTR nResponse = dlg->DoModal();`

---

The breakpoint on error is here: `ASSERT(ph[1] == h);`

```
   #ifdef _DEBUG
   void CHandleMap::RemoveHandle(HANDLE h)
   {
    // make sure the handle entry is consistent before deleting
    CObject* pTemp = LookupTemporary(h);
    if (pTemp != NULL)
    {
        // temporary objects must have correct handle values
        HANDLE* ph = (HANDLE*)((BYTE*)pTemp + m_nOffset);  // after CObject
        ASSERT(ph[0] == h || ph[0] == NULL);
        if (m_nHandles == 2)
            ASSERT(ph[1] == h); <------
    }
    pTemp = LookupPermanent(h);
    if (pTemp != NULL)
    {
        HANDLE* ph = (HANDLE*)((BYTE*)pTemp + m_nOffset);  // after CObject
        ASSERT(ph[0] == h);
        // permanent object may have secondary handles that are different
    }
    // remove only from permanent map -- temporary objects are removed
    //  at idle in CHandleMap::DeleteTemp, always!
    m_permanentMap.RemoveKey((LPVOID)h);
   }
   #endif
```

---

From the stack trace I can see the CDC is beging Detached, and prior to this the `CStatusBar` `OnNCPaint` is called. I have also inspected the WindowProc message value using the debugger, which is 133. I have looked up what 133 is, and it relates to `0085     133     WM_NCPAINT`. Alls seems irrelevant, except for the CDC being freed perhaps.

I suspect this happens when the application get's minimised - a wild guess, as I think this is what I did when it broke - also hard to reproduce.

Here is my statusbar code which might be applicable, note it's called from an OnTimer.

```
void MainDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
   if (nIDEvent == nTimerStatusbarUpdate)
   {
       if (statusBarHelper == nullptr) return;

      // snip...

      statusBarHelper->UpdateRightPanelWidthAndText(text);
   }
}


// the helper class method
void StatusBarHelper::UpdateRightPanelWidthAndText(const CString& text)
{
   if (statusbar_mutex.try_lock_for(std::chrono::seconds(1))) {
      CDC* pDC = statusBar.GetDC();
      If (pDC == nullptr)
      {
        // Failed to get device context
        statusbar_mutex.unlock();
        return;
      }
 
      // snip....

      // Release the device context and restore the original font
      pDC->SelectObject(pOldFont);
      statusBar.ReleaseDC(pDC);
      statusbar_mutex.unlock();
   }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: That's not a crash. It's a failed debug assertion caused by the system running into an unexpected state. The point of failure is inside MFC's GDI object garbage collector. The handle map is stored in thread local memory, and GDI objects have thread affinity. There's a mutex so maybe the issue is ultimately down to passing GDI objects across thread boundaries, directly or indirectly.

Comment: Thanks for that @IIinspectable. It's really helpful (point's me in the right direction where to look); It appears to be some threading issue. After some more inspection I found some more `CStatusbar` updates.  I noticed the use of "SendMesage" and "PostMessage" (yet to understand how this affects in which Thread the updates take place) that update `CStatusbar.`  I will start debugging this by tracking the ThreadID's that actually do the work, having a consistent ThreadID (the main GUI Thread for all UI updates).

Comment: Could you please mark answer for completion of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @IInspectable pointed out, it's not a stack trace but an assertion, which is part of the GDI garbage collection.

It was caused by call to detaching a CDC, when it should not have been called in the first place.

```
CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);

// snip 

pDC->Detach(); <-- the error
```

`CDC::FromHandle` returns a pointer to CDC, which is not under your control.

In my case the CDC being referenced was in DrawItem method.

`Clazz::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct) { ... }`

From Microsofts [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class?view=msvc-170):

> CDC::DeleteTempMap    Called by the CWinApp idle-time handler to delete any temporary CDC object created by FromHandle. Also detaches the device context.